# Calculating the Work to lift a Chain

Tags: calculus

Please Help!

A chain 63 meters long whose mass is 27 kilograms is hanging over the edge of a tall building and does not touch the ground. How much work is required to lift the top 11 meters of the chain to the top of the building? Use that the acceleration due to gravity is 9.8 meters per second squared. Hint: Don't forget that when you lift the top 11 meters of the cable you are also lifting the bottom 52 meters of the cable, just not all the way to the top.

Comment: Hint: Calculate the increase in potential energy.

Comment: So far this is what I did, does this look correct or even on the right track?
((27/63)(9.8))= 4.2
integrated from 0 to 11 of 4.2xdx

Comment: That would give you the increase in potential energy of the top $11$m.  Now add to that the increase in potential energy of the rest of the chain, which is $52$m long being pulled up $11$m. Actually, you don't need integration in these cases, if you just consider the centre of gravity going up.

Comment: Because energy is conserved in this problem (no friction), you can either integrate the force with respect to distance, or else calculate the change in potential energy.  Both are correct; the latter is often easier.

Comment: would calculating the potential energy of the rest of the chain be something like this?:
11(27/63)(52)(9.8)? and then I would add it to the potential energy found for the top of 11m?

Comment: Yes, you got the second part right too.

Answer (score 1):

Because energy is conserved in this problem (no friction), you can either integrate the force with respect to distance, or else calculate the change in potential energy.  Both are correct; the latter is often easier.

For the force approach, note that when $x$ meters of chain have been pulled up, there are $63-x$ meters remaining, with a mass of $27(1-x/63)=27-(3/7)x$ kilograms, and so you're exerting a force of $(27-(3/7)x)\times(9.8$ kg-m/s$^2$) along the direction of motion.  Integrating this gives
$$
\frac{W}{9.8J}=\int_{x=0}^{11}F(x)dx=\int_{x=0}^{11}\left(27-\frac{3x}{7}\right)dx=\left(27x-\frac{3x^2}{14}\right)\Bigg\vert_{x=0}^{11}=\frac{3795}{14},
$$
or $W=2656.5$ kg-m$^2$/s$^2$.

I'll leave the potential energy approach as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You could equivalently (for all physical aspects to consider) cut off the lower 11 meters and put them on top of the building. That way you lift $\frac{11}{63}$ of the total mass by $63-\frac{11}2$.

Comment: Very nice...[+1]